# PostgreSQL with JSONB vs MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, transactions, distributed-transactions, consistency

For a social media platform that I'm developing, I need to model the database for the user content. The content published by the user will be typically title, description, comments with replies and few hashtags. (Need full text search for description) The old platform has around 200K registered users.

For the database I'm thinking to have a PostgreSQL and a MongoDB instance. I need to use a PostgreSQL because there are some schema that I have to enforce and needs ACID compliant transactions. I was thinking to use MongoDB to store user content like title, description but having second thoughts whether **I really need a MongoDB instance**. I know PostgreSQL has this `JSON` and `JSONB` types and have used it before to store unstructured content. But if I go this way my only concern is that the performance of the search queries for `JSONB` and the complexity of the search queries that I have to implement. For example I may need a search feature where I have to search a phrase in several fields and sort the results based on a relevance score and return the results (like in elasticsearch and I think MongoDB has this automatically generated relevance score). So what do you guys think? Any tip or suggestion is much appreciated.

PS - In terms of the scalability, I'm not expecting to exceed 400K users in the next 5 years. Also if I use PostgreSQL and MongoDB, I have to have some kind of a two phase commit mechanism for the transactions that involves both the databases which is kind of an unnecessary effort at this point as I see.

Comment: Why are title and description "unstructured content"? Just create  table with two columns to store that. To me it sounds as if you are actually looking for [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) rather than some "JSON storage"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant is that it is possible to change the fields related to the user content, so needs some flexibility there. And yes! you are correct. I need full text search here but for the JSON data stored. Not sure about it's performance.

Comment: Postgres supports full text search on `jsonb` columns.

Comment: Yeah I checked. What do you think about its performance ?? Did some search around and some people claim its pretty bad when compared to the text fields.